# How do I find my user ID and group in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, user-accounts

Trying to run this compand in terminal:

```
sudo chown -R yourid:yourgroup local
```

However, I have no idea what my ID and my group are, or where to find them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

On OS X, your primary group is always `staff` unless you or your user directory manager changed it.

What's a *primary group*? The primary group of a user is by default the owner of all files created by that user.

---

For the purposes of `chmod` on your computer, you can use either your numeric user ID (e.g. 501), or your account name (e.g. `danielbeck`). The latter is different from the user name you usually see in the UI (e.g. *Daniel Beck*).

You can determine your account name using any of the following:

- It's the name of your home directory (unless you customized it) in Finder's title or side bar
- Run `whoami` in Terminal – so a `chown -R $(whoami):staff` should suffice. You can also get your primary group with `groups $(whoami) | cut -d' ' -f1`.
- Open *System Preferences » Users & Groups*, unlock the pane if necessary, right-click your user name (the single list entry in the *Current User* section), and select *Advanced Options…*. It's the field *Account Name* in the newly opened dialog window. This dialog also shows you your primary group.
- Run `id` in Terminal for more verbose output. This will include your numeric user ID. It'll also list all groups you're a member of, not just your primary group. The first group is the primary one.

Comment: Instead of using `whoami`, you can use `id` in a oneliner that is compatible with posix shells and csh. `chown -R \`id -u\`:\`id -g\` FOLDER`

Comment: If you use LDAP authentication your username won't necessarily be `staff`. Not on my work Mac OS X anyway.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat I address this in the second half of the first sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 65):

Use the `id` command from the terminal. It will display your uid and the groups you belong to. For example, 
here is my output showing my user id (534), group id (20) and the groups I belong to
(also 20).

```
uid=534(galuga) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff)
```

Answer (score 34):

This will show your userid.

```
$ id -u
502
```

This will show your group names. The group names are inside parentheses.

```
$ id
uid=502(whoami) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)
```

Answer (score 19):

Would only comment if I could.  I don't have enough karma on this site.

I have no idea why someone downvoted @callaginn, as he brings up a valid point.

The following methods are valid (and probably the best options for shell scripting):

```
id -u  # returns UID

id -un # returns username

id -g  # returns primary (a.k.a. effictive) GID

id -gn # returns primary Group Name
```

See `man id` for more options.

To answer this specific question if I was writing a script that would work in any environment, I wouldn't assume that the default group `staff` is in use and instead I would do the following if I was writing a script that could be run for any user (whether or not they modified their system):

```
chown "$(id -un):$(id -gn)" some_file
```

It's always better to be platform agnostic whenever possible (if it's not too much of a time tradeoff), as you will incur less technical debt later.

Please note that `chown`'s `-R` flag should be used with the utmost confidence.  You could really mess up your system (Although it is worth noting that Apple made it hard to do since they implemented `System Integrity Protection`).

Consider, for instance, if you were to `chown -R 755 /var` instead of `chown -R 755 /var/www` as root with `System Integrity Protection` disabled I believe that you would be in for it.  I can't tell you what would break first, but it would break first on a Darwin system, but please take my word that it wouldn't be pretty.

Hopefully, someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 8):

An even shorter method for finding the primary group:

```
id -gn
```

Comment: This is the magic one. So much cleaner than `groups $(whoami) | cut -d' ' -f1`.

Answer (score 5):

in Terminal, go to `~/Documents` and run `ls -la`. Your user name and group will be listed next to each of the files/directories.

It should look like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 username usergroup  4096 Oct 17  2012 Templates
```

Comment: super easy and straightforward, thanks for the tip.